A specific Feech La Manna quote
What was the episode of The Sopranos where Feech La Manna says to Adriana, 

If I need anything else one of the kids will come out

in the back room of the Crazy Horse nightclub?

All Happy Families (season 5, episode 4).

Adriana: Vodka rocks.
Feech: Thank you, dear.
Adriana: Anybody else?
Feech: If we need anything else, one of the kids'll come out.

By 'kids' I think he means Little Paulie and Benny, and possibly even Chris (which would be an insult).
Source: I watched the scene just now to verify it.
